# Contents of "Tactical Enhancement" and "Explosive Mission" DLC

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

So the "Tactical Enhancement Pack" and the "Explosive Mission Pack" DLC was released recently.

What do you get? I can see the weapons you get, but what are the levels? What else is included in the DLC?

Comment: I made some edits to focus on the content of the DLC. You can decide for yourself if it's worth getting once you get some responses.

Comment: Hang on a second... I don't think the Missing Link DLC has been released yet, has it? As far as I can see they've only released the "Tactical Enchancement" and "Explosive Mission" packs, which were what made up the various pre-order and retailer specific bonuses. (@Raven)

Comment: @AnnaLear Is it called "the missing link". I just left it as DLC, because I think DMA57361 is right... or is (s)he? I don't know!

Comment: No, it has not been released yet. I am an achievement hunter. I'd know when something like this is released ;).

Comment: Oh boy, I'm really sorry. I thought "Missing Link" was in your original wording, but I see now that it first appeared in @RavenDreamer's edit. We should have collectively fact-checked first. Sorry about screwing up your question... editing to fix now.

Comment: The 2 DLC in question are actually content keys, codes to unlock features already in the game.

Comment: @AnnaLear It's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tactical enhance pack provides:

> - The Huntsman Silverback double barreled shotgun.
> - The Longsword Whisperhead Silenced Sniper Rifle.
> - 10,000 extra Credits to start with.
>
> The bonus items are given at the first mission when riding the
>   helicopter with Sarif to the Milwaukee plant.  (The credits can ONLY
>   be obtained there).  The other items can be found at various
>   shopkeepers.

The explosive pack provides:

> - M-28 Remote explosive (the player starts with four of them)
> - Automatic Unlocking Device
> - a bonus mission ("You Scratch My Back, I'll Scratch Yours") involving Tracer Tong from> Deus Ex, which upon completion rewards the player with the LGTM linebacker G-87.

[source](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Deus_Ex:_Human_Revolution_Preorder_Packs)

Comment: Turned out that the Missing Link wasn't the DLC originally meant in the question. @RavenDreamer and I made an editing mistake there. Can you update your answer to cover the actually released packs? Thanks! (And sorry.)

Comment: @Anna Lear updated my answer.

Comment: So yx, have you got this content? And is it worth getting?

Comment: @Coomie worth getting is rather subjective.  Personally I love the silenced sniper rifle as I love silent take downs at long range.  I really felt that I was cheated by not being able to put a silencer on a sniper rifle like I could in the original, so having access to one now is a good way to make up for it.  As for the explosive pack, the bonus mission is a nice way of getting a little more experience to gain more praxis points with.